# GWT - uploading file to server without using FileUpload dialog

Tags: gwt

I have a requirement to upload a file to server from the web application written in GWT. The complex part is that FileUpload dialog box cannot be dislayed (due to space crunch issue on TabPanel). So on click of a button, I need to:

- Open the file selection directly, without bothering the user with an additional Form containing an UploadItem to click
- Start the upload immediately after file selection

I have written following code in GWT to open file select dialog box on click of button:

```java
final FileUpload upload = new FileUpload(); 
    
upload.setVisible(false);
upload.setName("uploadFormElement"); 
panel.add(upload);
    
panel.add(new Button("Select File", new ClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(Widget pSender) { 
         jsClickUpload( upload.getElement() );
         MessageBox.showMessage("selected filename: " + upload.getFilename());
    } 
}));
    
native void jsClickUpload(Element pElement) /*-{ pElement.click(); }-*/;
```

Although this does open the file select dialog on the button click, it simultaneously also shows the message box with blank value for file name.

So what I need is that only after file is selected, the message box is displayed. How can I do this? Also, how to upload the actual file to Server after this (M

Answer (score 8):

Here is a working example:

```java
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
 
    upload.setVisible(false);
    upload.setName("uploadFormElement");
    RootPanel.get().add(upload);

    Button b = new Button("Select File");
    b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            jsClickUpload(upload.getElement());
        }
    });
    
    upload.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
       @Override
        public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
            Window.alert(upload.getFilename());
        }
    });
    
    RootPanel.get().add(b);
}

native void jsClickUpload(Element pElement) /*-{
    pElement.click();
}-*/;
```

To upload it you need a Servlet receiving the upload. I use this additional library: http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/ You find all the code needed on their website.

Comment: No, it does not work. I am not able to see the MessageBox after the file is selected. What I need is that ONLY after the file is selected, the actual upload should get triggered (MessageBox is just a plaace holder for testing, it will get replaced with the actual servlet upload code).

Comment: I replaced the answer with a working example. This code runs perfectly fine for me using GWT 2.4.0

Comment: really appreciate your help however, it does not work for me. I am not able to see the Window.alert. I am using GWT 2.3.0 and I am testing the same in FF browser (latest version), but I don't think that should matter much.